# Vim: nnoremap to a method inside a method

Tags: vim

I have an object, which has a function, that can activate a remap with a method.
This remaps some key to another method.
However when I tried my attempt below, it will tell, that it doesn't know what `self` is, which seems obvious, as a remap just parses some text, but I can't figure out how else to do it.

I could just do what `activate()` does outside of a function, however this attempt here would save me quite some work.

```
" the prototype
let Object = {}

" constructor
function! Object.new()
    let newObject = copy(self)
    return newObject
endfunction

function! Object.activate()
    nnoremap a :call self.foo()
endfunction

function! Object.foo()
    ...
endfunction
```

Comment: Here is [an interesting article](http://of-vim-and-vigor.blogspot.fr/2013/08/not-classy-vimlpoo.html).

Comment: Thank you very much, especially the dict keyword may solve my predicament